# How to populate values in the past for unit testing Prometheus alerts that include an offset?

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, promql

I'm trying to test a recording rule for a Prometheus alert.

This works as expected:

```
# test_file.yaml
rule_files:
  - "../records.yaml"

evaluation_interval: 1m

group_eval_order:
  - records

tests:
  - name: "Some test"
    interval: 1m
    input_series:
      - series: 'some_metric{somelabel="somevalue"}'
        values: '1+0x144000'

    promql_expr_test:
      - expr: recording_rule:under_test
        exp_samples:
          - labels: recording_rule:under_test{somelabel="somevalue"}
            value: 1
```

This is `records.yaml`:

```
  - expr: avg_over_time(some_metric{}[24h:]) > 0
    record: recording_rule:under_test
```

As expected, the recording rule includes `some_metric` and that makes the test pass.

The problem starts when I try to add an offset to the recording rule.

```
  - expr: avg_over_time(some_metric{}[24h:] offset 1w) > 0
    record: recording_rule:under_test
```

Then the test fails. I initially thought this was because the `input_series` only populates data in the future and the recording rule was searching in the past. I tried offseting the test to the future:

```
    promql_expr_test:
      - expr: recording_rule:under_test offset -1w
        exp_samples:
          - labels: recording_rule:under_test{somelabel="somevalue"}
            value: 1
```

But, that didn't work. I also tried adding an offset for `input_series`, but that isn't syntactically possible.